# What's the difference between currentIndexChanged and currentTextChanged PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5

What is the difference between currentIndexChanged and currentTextChanged PyQt5?

Answer (score 2):

The documentation should be self-explanatory well enough:

> [`currentIndexChanged(index)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcombobox.html#currentIndexChanged)
>
> This signal is sent whenever the [`currentIndex`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcombobox.html#currentIndex-prop) in the combobox changes either through user interaction or programmatically.

> [`currentTextChanged(text)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcombobox.html#currentTextChanged)
>
> This signal is sent whenever [`currentText`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcombobox.html#currentText-prop) changes.

Some clarifications might be required, though, mostly due to the following aspects:

1. a combobox can also be [`editable`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcombobox.html#editable-prop);
2. there can be multiple items that have the same text;

This leads to some important aspects that must be considered:

- in case the combo is editable, the current index is not updated until the combo loses focus, *or* the popup is shown (with an existing item text that matches the typed text), or by pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> after editing;
- if it's not editable and multiple items share the same text, setting the `currentText` will automatically set the index (and the text) on the *first* item that matches that text, which *could* cause both signals to be fired whenever the current item is not the first occurrence of that text;
- the `currentTextChanged` behavior changes depending on the `editable` property: if it's editable, it's based on the underlying `QLineEdit` text changed signal, otherwise it will be sent anyway, even if the text is the same;

So, this means that:

- if the combo is *not* editable, both signals will be emitted, even if the text is the same;
- if the combo *is* editable, editing the text alone won't change the current index: you need to press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, or change focus in any way (even by showing the popup) as long as the typed text matches an existing item in the model;
- if the combo is editable, then focus is changed and the typed text doesn't match any item, the current index is obviously not changed;
- changing the current index will emit the `currentTextChanged` signal only if the combo is editable *or* the item text is different: otherwise, if the new index has the same text, only the index signal is emitted; this is also valid whenever the item is selected from the popup;